# Is smoking allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, smoking

I have studied somewhere that smoking is haram but people who use to smoke say it not haram it makrooh.

I want to know is it haram (like alcohol) or it just makroo?

Can anyone give me proper evidence on this matter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The body which we are using isn't our own property, it is what Allah has given us to use and live in the world and Allah will take it back once we will die. Allah has forbidden harming yourself and this is the reason why suicide is haram in Islam because it is **self-harm.**

> [image]
>   And spend in the way of Allah and **do not throw [yourselves] with your [own] hands into destruction [by refraining]**. And do good; indeed, Allah loves the doers of good. [Surat Al-Baqarah - 195](http://quran.com/2/195)

*This ayah tells what I am talking about.*

You are talking about smoking so as far as I know, smoking cause mouth cancer and it is same as **self-harm** so it isn't better for you to smoke.

Comment: Brother I don't smoke but there are two views I agree with you but Is it any hadith which state that smoking is haram like alcohol.

Comment: I don't think there would be any ayah or hadith related to smoking but it is common-sense if anything is harmful then it shouldn't be used because we know it can harm and **Thanks**.

Comment: Of course there would be no ayah on Smoking because smoking was invented well after the coming of the prophet. The above lesson that Murtaza is giving is that any form of self harm is NOT allowed in Islam. Let's take drugs for example, ecstasy was not in the days of the prophet, though it's clear that it is not permissible. Just like smoking. Scholars however have a difference of opinion whether it is haraam or makrooh. At the very least, it is most certainly makrooh. Let's also not forget that it is haraam to displease another person by smoking next to them!

Comment: if that's your reasoning, eating sweets for Eid is self-harm because it makes one obese so should it be considered haram?

Comment: @amphibient first of all, don't compare sweet with smoking because there is huge different in it. Second, eating sweet won't make obese but eating too much can someone obese. One more thing, Allah doesn't like those people who are obese because of eating too much, check this [Hadit](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/15).

Comment: @Xitas I do not know why you are asking for a hadith. Surely you realise that tobacco was unknown in the Old World before the discovery of America. That was about 900 years after the time of our Prophet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to being destruction, as said in other answer, there are other reasons:

- 1) it is israf, and israf is prohibited in many ayats. It is israf
  because it is waste of time of you and all resources that are spent
  (work and water etc.) and used (fields) and destructed (wild nature
  that was in place of fileds) to produce and transport cigarettes.
- 2) It is changing of what is made by Allah that is prohibited in
  Quran 4:119.

What is haram? If anything that is prohibited by Allah in Quran is haram than it is haram.