# Is oxygen shots/bar allowed in Islam

Tags: halal-haram, smoking

I have Ask a question about [**Smoking**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/is-smoking-allowed-in-islam) but this is different from it

There is a new thing raising called `"Oxygen Bar"`. It is almost same like `'Sheesha'` but it is oxygen instead of smoke. But there is difference in Oxygen shot/bar that you lost your consciousness for few minutes(not sure of it). I heard that there are few `advantages` of it and few `disadvantages` but I am not sure about that.

> So can anyone tell me Is it right or wrong for our health and explain it in view of Islam?

[**Here is wiki about oxygen bar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_bar)

Comment: As far as I heard, Sheeshe is considered as a dangerous material which is more dangerous than other smoking such as cigarette and so forth. In the mentioned position, it could be haram as a material which has much disadvantage ..

Comment: According to the article in Wikipedia, this is more of a medical question than [tag:halal-haram].

Comment: @ozbek yes that's true. but want a Islamic view about this.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that pure oxygen is used by pilots and in hospitals. The only effect is to make you feel more energetic. I don't know where you'd heard that you'll lose consciousness, but that's not a result of inhaling pure oxygen.

Comment: Correction: it's not completely pure Oxygen, it's air with a higher Oxygen content. Pure Oxygen is toxic.

Comment: I searched online to find where it says oxygen bars makes you unconsciousness, but I couldn't find any, can you please share a quote about that.

Comment: @Honey i have never done it but i heard which i think not true. someone with the experience can tell us.

Answer (score 4):

**Anything which make you unconscious even for a second, is considered wrong!**

Not only in Islam, but it is general. Just consider the fact that wine, alcohol, etc are not allowed due to their unconscious effects on us. Therefore, this statement might be considered right that:

**Islam do not allow anything that make us out of our control!**

If this reason is not solid, then I ask you that why taking any decision while being angry is not allowed or **haram**! Therfore, the above statement proves to be right.

**Excess of anything is bad!**

Ofcourse, oxygen bar have disadvantages due to the fact that we are inhaling excess oxygen. We are already taking it! Whatever, its irrelevant.

**Oxygen Bar is not allowed in Islam!**

Comment: Mashallah, very good answer. But if you could add the hadith of "doubetful matters" would improve it more. as if someone still have doubt,then he should leave that matter

Comment: @Farhan narrations are good, but we really don't need a narration to tell us putting a nail in your eye is bad or do we? (I'm exaggerating a bit, hopefully you get my point). Our own intellect suffices us for many many things, in fact when prophets come mostly they don't **insert** anything into your minds, they just **retrieve** what was already there by *admonitions* (*تذکر*). What I mean is the prophet doesn't come to tell us oppression is bad, he simply says respect your parents and we're like "oh oh may bad yes sure, I won't do it again"

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with ozbek on this one. Halal is the default position of Islam, so new things will be Halal unless an authority deems it Haram. Oxygen bars don't have any negative health effects and don't actually influence your thinking, so there's nothing really wrong with them. But they are a waste of time and resources, which **is** something discouraged in Islam.

Common sense tells me it's something to avoid.

Comment: down vote,as your answer is merely opinion based, lacks proper knowlde=ge about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this affect your brain & make you out of control for 3 minutes.Therefore this is dangerous and totally haram in Islam.

Answer (score -1):

Oxygen bars have oxygen mixed with certain chemicals which r harmful and these are chemicals which make you intoxicated for some time that's why I think that this is HARAM.